# How to bind function to object?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

**Full code is:**

```
export interface IButton {
  click: Function;
  settings?: IButtonSettings;
}

abstract class Button implements IButton {
  click() {}

}

 class ButtonReset extends Button {
    super()
 }
```

**Component is:**

```
export class ButtonsComponent {
private a = "Message";
constructor() {
  let btn = new ButtonReset();
  btn.click = this.alert;
  btn.click(); // Here I want to get console.log(this.a);
}

public alert() {
  console.log(this.a);
 }

}
```

Why I can not bind method `alert()` to instance `new ButtonReset();` then call it?

More simple sample:

```
class A {
  public message = "message 1";
  public b: any;
}

class B {
 public message = "message";
   c() {
      console.log(this.message);
   }

}

let instanceA = new A();
let instanceB = new B();

instanceA.b = instanceB.c;
instanceA.b();
```

I need to get `message` instead `message 1`

Comment: You should define the relation between class A and B first.

Comment: It would help people give you clear, helpful answers if you gave a complete example of what you're trying to do, along with what result you get (for instance, should `items` come from an instance of `A` or from `b`?).

Comment: I have updated my question with full code listed

Comment: Yes, see my question where I tried bind it and then call

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want to bind `this.alert` to `btn`? that would not work becase `a` is a member of `ButtonsComponent` and does not actually exist on `ButtonReset`

Comment: Yes, I want bind component method alert to button. And call it through btn instance. Because each button has click event, but handler of this click is placed in specific component(class), where I use btn

Comment: Is the code you shared not doing that right now? What's the problem?

Comment: Problem is instead message `a` I get `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an *instance* of `A` (let's call it `a`) and want the call to `get` to return that instance's `items`, then you'd use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create a bound function to assign to `b.get`:

```
b.get = a.get.bind(a);
```

JavaScript example:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }
    get() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
class B {
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
b.get = a.get.bind(a);
console.log(b.get()); // `[]`, from `a.items`
```

But if you want the *logic* of `A.prototype.get` applied to the `b` instance (so it gets `b.items`), then:

```
b.get = A.prototype.get;
```

JavaScript example:

```js
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }
    get() {
        return this.items;
    }
}
class B {
    constructor() {
        this.items = 42;
    }
}

const b = new B();
b.get = A.prototype.get;
console.log(b.get()); // `42`, because `b.items` is `42`
```

---

In both cases, you'll need to provide a type for `b` that says it has a `get` method now, e.g. something like:

```
interface BPlus extends B {
    get(): any;
}
```

You may also want a new identifier with that type:

```
const bp = <BPlus>b;    // Not true yet...
bp.get = a.get.bind(a); // Now it is
```

*([On the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4CcCWA3MALgKbTbEC2EAXNGAHYCeA2gLrQC80rA3EimugCuAIxDZg0AOZECACgCUifmjSYZgzHWgEAFtggA6MkUq8VAXySXQkGACEllpNjrFMAMzDASdgAohBGCIAD2I6ABN7JRVpOXkaegZeJ2AAezoIAloOaDoiAHc4BV40jKzhHLzCu2KkUszoYXQcgB4-AIgAPmFuaAB6PugAOVSsgkxBEgYZA1mkJoNYnLBFmeEXcNkweV6B4dTCslIIOvSIVJAiAxBUyVkF2IUd-sGAA1ZXgBpod0xU8mgrxWxkoryAA))*